# Check for duplicates in a file of over 2GB

Tags: ruby, list, parsing, memory, memory-management

I have a large list of words that has been compiled from various sources. Having come from so many unrelated sources, I imagine there are some duplicates. Even inside some of the original files, there are duplicates. I've created a script to sort them out, but the file has gotten so ungainly at this point that I run out of memory when trying to parse it. The source is below. I'm running Windows 8, 64-bit, with Ruby 1.9.3-p327.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

words = []
File.foreach( "wordlist.txt" ) do |line|
    words << line
end
words.uniq!()
words = words.sort()

wordFile = File.open( "wordlist.txt", "w" )

words.each do |word|
    wordFile << word + "\n"
    puts "Wrote to file: #{ word }"
end
```

Comment: do an [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). then iterate the list, looking for where a word equals the previous word.

Comment: Do you have access to SQLite? How about [DBM](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/dbm/rdoc/index.html)?

Comment: @muistooshort I do have access to DBM, and I may be able to set up SQLite.

Comment: You can use DBM as an on-disk Hash and a Hash's keys are unique so the keys can be used as a set. With SQLite you could create a table with a unique constraint and then insert your data and ignore constraint violations, what's left at the end is your unique set of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways of removing duplicates. You don't need to do this in ruby for one. If the words fit in memory you can use a set of words that you've seen once, and not print those again. If the set is too big, you can always sort the file outside of ruby using the `sort` command (look into the -T switch to use a temporary directory instead of memory), and pipe the output into `uniq -c`.

Comment: Of course the OP is using Windows, so these core Unix utilities are not built-in.

Comment: I'd love to use Unix utilities, and I am quite familiar with them, but I am unfortunately tied down to Windows at the moment.

Comment: @Mark: AFAIR Linux is free to download from the internet. Yay!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yes, yes it is. And I would love to have it and not be required to be on Windows. However, this is not my personal computer that these operations are being run on.

Comment: Would the real owner be OK with you installing Cygwin?  (I know, obvious, but "for the record...".)

Comment: @DigitalRoss Surprisingly yes. Nice call! I had forgotten about Cygwin. I'm starting up the installation now.

Comment: @Mark Doesn’t Windows have its own `sort`? This link – http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491004.aspx – suggests there was one in XP, but I can’t find any reference about Windows 8.